# Why do you need to import java.util.* to use Arrays.toString()

Tags: java

The `Arrays.toString()` would not work without `import java.util.*` for some reason. Here is a simple java code that deletes an element from an array by the length of the string that the user inputs.

```
import java.util.*;
public class conjunction {
    public static String func(String x[], int input) {
        String temp[] = new String[x.length - 1];
        String temp2[] = new String[x.length - 1];
        for (int c = 0; c < x.length; c++) {
            if (x[c].length() == input & c + 1 < x.length) {
                temp2[c] = x[c + 1];
                x[c + 1] = x[c];
                x[c] = temp2[c];
            } else if (x[c].length() != input) {
                temp[c] = x[c];
            }
        }
        return Arrays.toString(temp);
    }

}
```

It says it cannot resolve symbol Arrays.

Comment: this is just the method class not the main()

Comment: The `Arrays` class sits in `java.util` package. This class provides static methods to dynamically create and access Java arrays. Since you are using `Arrays.toString`, you need to import the package to use it

Answer (score 9):

That's because the [`Arrays` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) lives in package `java.util`, so you either need to import it explicitly (with `import java.util.Arrays;`) or you import everything from that package (with the wildcard `import java.util.*;`)

More generally, everything in Java lives in a package and needs to be imported, with the exception of the [`java.lang` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html), where classes like `String` live, which is imported by default.

Answer (score 6):

An `import` is **never** required in Java, and in fact it does not exist at the byte-code level. Your code will work if you remove the import statement and change your `return` to

```
return java.util.Arrays.toString(temp);
```

An `import` reduces the typing required at development time (it is a programmer *convenience*).

Answer (score 3):

`import java.util.Arrays;` also works

Comment: Not only does it also work, it's also generally the better way to go.

Answer (score 2):

using `import` statement is vary beginner OOP concept in JAVA.. according to your question `toString(temp)` is a static method of `Arrays` class. And the `Arrays` class belongs to package `java.util`, so using that static method you need to `import java.util.Arrays`. point to be noted every java class by default import `java.lang.*`

here i am sharing some thought about package.

Every thing in JAVA belong to package. Package are used in Java, in-order to avoid name conflicts and to control access of class, interface and enumeration etc. A package can be defined as a group of similar types of classes, interface, enumeration or sub-package. Using package it becomes easier to locate the related classes and it also provides a good structure for projects with hundreds of classes and other files.

Mainly Java project support two Types of Packages: **Built-in** and **User defined**

**Using import keyword**

`import` keyword is used to import built-in and user-defined packages into your java source file so that your class can refer to a class that is in another package by directly using its name.

There are 3 different ways to refer to any class that is present in a different package:

1. Using fully qualified name (But this is not a good practice.): Like  `return java.util.Arrays.toString(temp);`This is generally used when two packages have classes with same names. For example: `java.util` and `java.sql` packages contain `Date class`.
2. To import only the class/classes you want to use : Like `import java.util.Arrays;`. then only the class with name `Arrays` in the package with name `util` will be available for use.
3. To import all the classes from a particular package: Like `import java.util.*`. it make all the classes and interfaces of this package (`util` package) will be accessible but the classes and interface inside the subpackages will not be available for use.

**Points to remember**

- When a package name is not specified, the classes are defined into the default package and the package itself is given no name.
- **`Java.lang.*` package in Java**: Provides classes that are fundamental to the design of the Java programming language.

Answer (score 1):

toString() is a method inside Arrays class(static) and this class is in the package java.util.The source file for this class is in package named util which is in a package named java.

Also we can use package qualifiers instead of import.
The import statement is not always required.Class reference can be made with explicit qualification with "." operator.
eg `java.util.ArrayList<String> str //fully qualified`

There is one situation where qualification in necessary- when two classes have same name but are in different packages.
eg`java.util.Timer` and `java.swing.Timer`
Here the name Timer is ambiguous and can't be used without qualification.